# More efficient way of getting things from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I am writing a program that you can enter keywords into to get something back, but the method of using 'if-elif-else' statements doesn't seem like a very efficient way to do this. Is there a better way I could do this? Here is some code for reference:

```
things = {
    "word": "desc."
    #So on and so forth
}

def check():
    find = raw_input("> ")
    if find == "word":
        print things["word"]
        get_check()
    #So on and so forth with the elif's and else's
    elif find == "exit":
        print ""

def get_check():
    check()

check()
```

If there isn't a more efficient way to do this, please tell me. (I would think there would be though.) Also, sorry about the title, I don't know many technical terms that I should use. So feel free to edit title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out if a key is in a dictionary using `in`:

```
if find in things:
    print things[find]
```

or just use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to return the value associated with the key or `None`:

```
print things.get(find)
```

Comment: What would I replace key with when I re-write this?

Comment: ...whatever you want to use as a key! From your example, `find`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if find == 'exit':
  # Exit
else:
  item = things.get(find)
  if item is not None:
    # Do something with item
  else:
    # find not found
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'do something with item?'

Comment: `item` is the value in the dictionary. Now you have to do something with it.